# Vue.js validator reset specific validator

Tags: vue.js, vue-validator

I have a template which contains multiple forms which all have their own validator. When I have submitted the form I'd like to reset the validator.

From what I've read from the documentation you can only use the `this.$resetValidation();` method which only works on one of the validators.

How can i reset the validation of a specific validator?
Is there a workaround?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle modeling the problem?

Comment: From https://github.com/vuejs/vue-validator/issues/220, there is not a blessed way of making this happen.  Calling `$resetValidation()` only works on the most recently defined validator.